# Animate absolute object from right: 0 to left: 0 in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, absolute

So I have a jQuery function that animates a set of -elements with different width from aligning to the right of the parent div, to the left of the parent div.
This works smothly in firefox, however in Chrome the animation "jumps" instead of animating smothly to the otherside. Has anyone an idea of a fix for this?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WM9nQ/

HTML:

```
     <body> 
      <div id="parent">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
width: 500px;  
}

#parent{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

#parent ul li{
height: 20px;
width: 100%;
margin: 2px 0px;
list-style: none;
}

#parent a{
    color: #000;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function($){
   $('#parent a').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
                $('#parent a').animate({
                    left: 0
                    }, 2000);       
                });
});
```

Comment: can you please put all this code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WM9nQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it instantly goes to the left is because you have not set the left position of the element, as a result jQuery tries to go from the computed `left:auto` to `left:0`

To get around this you could set the left position before performing the animation:

```
var element = $('#parent li a:eq(0)');

var left = element.position().left;

element.css({ left: left });

element.delay(100).animate({
    left: "0px"
}, 'slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KQGQr/2/

Or you could animate using the right position of the element:

```
$('#parent a').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var element = $('#parent li a:eq(0)');

    element.delay(100).animate({
        right: $('#parent').width() - element.outerWidth()
    }, 'slow');       
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KQGQr/3/

Comment: This works quite fine, the only thing is that it makes a small "jump" to the right before performing the animation.

Comment: Better, still since it is a row of "right:0" positioned objects they still make a small jump to "left:aligned" before animation. Better, but not perfect... hmm...

Comment: I couldn't really see the jump, so not sure if this does the trick but try the new update

Comment: Ah it was because all a-tags had equal width. Check out new fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/KQGQr/4/
Now the animation ends with the <a>-elemnts right-aligned, My wish is that they will animate from right-aligned tow left-aligned :)